# "Went for the deep cut"

Tags: expressions, slang

I've done some searching but still can't fully understand this sentence. Can somebody explain to me?

[image]

Comment: That’s Will Smith in the middle, and actor who rose to fame in a 90s/00s sitcom “Fresh Prince of Bel-Air”. Both the fans are dressed up as his character from that show. The guy on the right in the hat with the camera is dressed up as the kind of instantly-recognizable iconic version of the character from the weekly musical intro. The guy on the left is dressed more obscurely from [this scene](https://memegenerator.net/img/images/600x600/14907585/will-smith-sunflower.jpg). That image has become a meme, so the slang “deep cut” must mean either “obscure reference” or “sharp insult”. Unsure which.

Comment: A **[deep cut](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Deep%20Cut)** refers to a song (or bit of knowledge) that only devoted fans will recognize.

Comment: @user159691 I suspect this use of “cut” is slangy and novel enough that its exact sense isn’t recorded in any dictionary yet. I have some friends who speak a similar dialect of English to the one displayed in those comments, and I’ve heard “cut” used for many things, including “track on a record”, which I haven’t heard outside that language community. I’m pretty sure the guy means “obscure reference” (the insult theory is possible but not as credible in this situation, because dressing up as a character, even a meme’d one, reflects enjoyment of that character).

Comment: @Davo Nice! Well found. So it is an obscure reference.

Comment: @DanBron it feels like radio station DJs have used the term "deep cut" for a "non-single track" since I was in high school, but I can't decide if this is a Philadelphia specific usage (Will Smith in the OP reference and I both growing up in the area) or a music industry usage (Will Smith being a multiplatinum recording artist as well as actor)

Comment: @user662852 Defintiely not PA only. At least for the more general equivalence of “cut == track” (as opposed to theory specific “non single track”). My friends from Louisiana (both urban and rural) use it. It has a street feel to it.

Comment: An interesting question would be whether *cut* referring to a recording derives from the cutting of tape to make a record or the groove in the record that corresponds to a particular track on the record.  *OED* citations seem to point to either possibility.

Comment: @Davo Here's a youtube clip from an old Fresh Prince of Bel-Air episode that explains why your explanation of "deep cut" is the correct one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktc5-jCqf5w

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime: I am pretty sure that people referred to individual songs on a vinyl LP as _cuts_ at least as far back as the 1970s, so I'm confident that the expression referred originally to the groove cut in the vinyl (or before that, wax) platter—what Howard Devoto of early XTC called the "spiral scratch". It is also possible that the expression came from the visual striping that separates one song from another on an LP. At a dance party that featured songs from LPs, cuing was a major skill, especially as the quantity of beer imbibed by the DJ started adding up.

Comment: @SvenYargs Those are all good points and that was my initial guess as well.  What gave me pause was the earliest *OED* cite from 1949, which uses "cut" as a verb and a noun in the same sentence:  *A recording artist cuts a master and the recording executive may reject the cut.*  - *Music Library Association Notes*, 1949.  I assume that the cinema term "cut" refers to cutting tape and appears to predate the music term as well by a decade or so.  Like I said, it was enough to give me pause, but on the whole, I agree with your assessment.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime: Couldn't *cutting a master* refer to cutting a track in a wax cylinder or disc, which started long before sound was recorded on magnetic tapes? The *OED* has "1937   L. Lewis *Radio Dict.* in *Printers' Ink Monthly*  Cut a disk, to make a recording."

Answer (score 3):

A *cut* is slang for a song, as in a cut off an album. A *deep cut* is a lesser-known song, one that devoted fans may be familiar with, but average fans might not. In the photo, the dude on the left is dressed up as Will Smith, in a costume seen in an episode of *Fresh Prince of Bellaire*. Here is a scene from that episode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adwT8ZY-XHM.

Answer (score 1):

@DanBron in the comments posted:

> That’s Will Smith in the middle, and actor who rose to fame in a 90s/00s sitcom “Fresh Prince of Bel-Air”.
>
> Both the fans are dressed up as his character from that show. The guy on the right in the hat with the camera is dressed up as the kind of instantly-recognizable iconic version of the character from the weekly musical intro. The guy on the left is dressed more obscurely from this scene. That image has become a meme, so the slang “deep cut” must mean either “obscure reference” or “sharp insult”. Unsure which
>
> I have some friends who speak a similar dialect of English to the one displayed in those comments, and I’ve heard “cut” used for many things, including “track on a record”, which I haven’t heard outside that language community. I’m pretty sure the guy means **“obscure reference”**  (the insult theory is possible but not as credible in this situation, because dressing up as a character, even a meme’d one, reflects enjoyment of that character).
>
> [Dec 20 at 13:08](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423085/went-for-the-deep-cut#comment1012787_423085) and [Dec 20 at 13:17](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423085/went-for-the-deep-cut#comment1012791_423085)

Comment: I'm looking at some Stephen Colbert's old interviews on The Late Show, and one of them has Mathew McConaughey as a guest. Turns out that the charismatic actor is a big fan of a Stephen Colbert's 1992 show. He knows the lines of and punchlines of every skit, Stephen Colbert is astonished, he doesn't even remember the script of the shows because it was so long ago.

Comment: With McConaughey the two perform an old skit from the show and you can tell Mathew knew the lines by heart, there's no need for a teleprompter. A YouTuber writes in the [comments section](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tC0uJK3VcTk) `Damn i thought that Stephen had a big crush on him but it seems to go both ways. Cause Exit 57 is a deep cut, I'm still waiting for someone to come and reenact Down In The Basement` EDIT: The show was broadcast in 1995

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it will mean he went very far. For example, say your teacher gives you a project, with specific instructions, but you, you go for the deep cut and add in a couple more things that will make your project better. Your teacher might say, "Wow! You went for the deep cut!", as in "Wow! You went very far".