# Does "cut" meaning "an audio recording" derive from cutting tape or from the grooves (cuts) in vinyl records (or other)?

Tags: etymology

This is prompted by another question and [the ensuing comment discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423085/went-for-the-deep-cut#comment1015688_423085):

- ["Went for the deep cut"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423085/went-for-the-deep-cut)

This question is about the word "cut" meaning a track on a record; an audio recording.  The *OED* gives this definition:

> A gramophone record or recording.

It seems like the natural assumption would be that the "cut" refers to the groove in the record, because in contemporary speech a "cut" usually refers to a single track on a larger "album."

However, the earliest attested use in the *OED* uses "cut" as a verb and a noun in the same sentence, making it sound like the noun "cut" derived from the *act* of cutting, as in cutting tape for a reel-to-reel recording device.

> A recording artist **cuts** a master and the recording executive may reject the ***cut***.

- **1949** -  *Music Libr. Assoc. Notes* Dec. 42

Is there any evidence or arguments in favor of an etymology of this modern sense of the word "cut" based on either the groove theory or the tape-cutting theory, or is there an alternative explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that

- creating a vinyl record starts with a mastering lathe physically *cutting* grooves in a lacquer master;
- the creation of phonograph records (1877) predates the use of tape (1950's) to record and optimize the sound before committing it to a master disc by almost 80 years [[How Records are Made](https://gizmodo.com/5987010/how-records-are-made)];

I would say that *cut* derives from phonograph recording technology.

Also note that a *[cutting room](https://thevinylfactory.com/features/how-to-master-a-record-noel-summerville-vinyl-dubplates-the-clash/)* refers to the area where the mastering lathes are operated. (Which is a very different sense than its use in the [film industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_room_floor).)

(Also, I can state from experience that one physically cuts an audio tape mainly to perform [manual editing and splicing](https://tapeop.com/tutorials/11/intro-analog-tape-splicing-and-editing-and-tape-loops/).)

Comment: Interesting. I always thought that you could cut an audio tape in the exact same sense that you cut celluloid, and that "a cut" could mean "the piece of tape that was snipped out of the master tape and discarded", and later came to mean "a piece of tape" per se.

Comment: @MrLister you can, but it isn't :)